# Subclass python ContextVar

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-contextvars

Is there a legal pythonic way to store one additional attribute in `ContextVar`?

I can't subclass `ContextVar` because of `TypeError`

I can

```py
    from contextvars import ContextVar as BaseContextVar

    class ContextVar:
        def __init__(self, name, *, default: Optional[Any], key: Optional[str]):
            self._var = BaseContextVar(name, default=default)
            self.key = key
```

but I'm not sure that there will be no side effects

P. S. Of course, I can store additional values in mapping. But I don't like this